# White space between bottom of photo sets and border

Tags: html, css, image, whitespace, tumblr

I was getting white spaces between the bottom of image posts and the border on my tumblr page. I inserted `vertical-align: bottom;` in this line of css

```
.entries img { 
vertical-align: bottom;    
{block:ifbiggerposts}max-width:500px;{/block:ifbiggerposts}
{block:ifnotbiggerposts}max-width:400px;{/block:ifnotbiggerposts}
{block:iffadingimages}{block:indexpage}opacity:.7;{/block:indexpage}{/block:iffadingimages}
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;}
```

Now the white spaces are only showing up under the photosets. I tried inserting

```
img {
display:block;
}
```

but that didnt fix the problem either.

Here is the pastebin for my theme http://pastebin.com/2iE93Hq3

Here is my tumblr page: http://neverwakeasnorlax.tumblr.com/

An example of the problem is the 3rd post down with the gifs of the Pokemon Zapdos Moltres and Articuno

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin on the div containers that creates a gap:

```
.photoset .photoset_row {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I looked through my theme and I couldn't find that line of code anywhere . How can I fix it so there isn't a space? I'm definitely a novice at this

Comment: Can you please walk me through what to do here

Comment: I didn't actually realise these were pulled in through an iframe. You can't alter what's in the iframe from your site. You have to alter it at the source, if you have access.

Comment: Sadly the OP won't have access to the source due to how Tumblr implements iframe based Photosets.